# Finding a combination of integers whose sum is greater than the given value.(Repetition is allowed)

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory

We have a set of integers and we want to find the frequency of each integer so that the sum of the integers exceeds a given value and if we remove any non-zero frequency integer from the sum, the sum should drop below the given value.
Example : Integers = {1,2,3,5} values = 25
Answer : Frequencies : 0,0,9,0 and if we remove 3 (non-zero frequency integer), the sum drops below 25. 
Note : There can be multiple answers.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about the [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem)

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you wish to find *all* solutions for a given set of integers and value?

Comment: When you remove $3$ does the sum become $0$ or $24$?  That is, do you remove one $3$ or all of them?

Comment: In your example does $0,0,0,5$ fail (sum does not exceed $25$) and does $0,0,0,6$ fail (removing an integer leaves a sum not below $25$)?

Comment: I remove only one integer i.e. whose frequency is non-zero. I will remove one 3 in the given example. I only want one such combination in which if I remove the integer with a non-zero frequency once, the sum will drop below the value. 0,0,0,5 fail because I want the sum to be greater than the given value. 0,0,0,6 fails because sum remains >= 25 after removing 5. @RossMillikan.

Comment: @Henry Please read above

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Please read above

Comment: I remove only the integers whose frequency is non-zero and I do that only once. By removing any integer which has a non-zero frequency, the sum should drop below the value. This should happen with all the integers having a non-zero frequency. I will remove one 3 in the given example. I only want one such combination in which if I remove the integer with a non-zero frequency once, the sum will drop below the value. 0,0,0,5 fail because I want the sum to be greater than the given value. 0,0,0,6 fails because sum remains >= 25 after removing 5. @RossMillikan.

Answer (score 1):

You need the sum to exceed the target by less than the smallest number used.  You can't use any $1$s ever, as the sum has to drop by at least $2$ to go from above to below the target.  If you use any $2$s, the sum must be one more than the target, so any combination of $2$s, $3$s, and $5$s that adds to $26$ is a solution.  Some of them are $(0,13,0,0),\ \ (0,10,2,0),\ \ (0,8,0,2)$ but there are many more.  If you don't use any $2$s the sum can be $26$ or $27$, so $(0,0,2,4)$ and $(0,0,4,3)$ are solutions.  If you only use $5$s you could accept $26$ to $29$ as a sum, but cannot get there with only $5$s.

Comment: Thanks! I will think about that.

Comment: You can find a solution using only one number any time the number does not divide the target.  I showed the one using $13$ twos and you showed the one using $9$ threes.  As $5|25$ there is not one using only $5$s.  If you had $6$ available you could use $5$ sixes.